# How can I toggle all other divs using addClass removeClass?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to customise an existing bit of jQuery code for toggled content to allow me to close all other divs than the one I have clicked.

The code:

```
$('.et_lb_toggle_title').click(function(){
        var $this_heading = $(this),
            $module = $this_heading.closest('.et_lb_toggle'),
            $content = $module.find('.et_lb_toggle_content');

        $content.slideToggle(700);

        if ( $module.hasClass('et_lb_toggle_close') ){
            $module.removeClass('et_lb_toggle_close').addClass('et_lb_toggle_open');
        } else {
            $module.removeClass('et_lb_toggle_open').addClass('et_lb_toggle_close');
        }
    });
```

Currently this allows more than one div to be opened. What I'd like to achieve is when you open one div, all others close.

I think I need to target all other divs using

```
$('.et_lb_toggle_title').not($(this))
```

I've been struggling with it for a while and now my head is spinning!

Here's a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xSK7K/) if it helps. NB (The divs are usually closed by default).

Any help, as always would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $contents = $('.et_lb_toggle_content').hide();
var $modules = $('.et_lb_toggle').addClass('et_lb_toggle_close');
$('.et_lb_toggle_title').click(function(){
    var $this_heading = $(this),
        $module = $this_heading.closest('.et_lb_toggle'),
        $content = $module.find('.et_lb_toggle_content');

    $content.stop(true, true).slideToggle(700);
    $contents.not($content).stop(true, true).slideUp();

    $module.toggleClass('et_lb_toggle_open et_lb_toggle_close');
    $modules.not($module).removeClass('et_lb_toggle_open').addClass('et_lb_toggle_close');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JvL7n/)

Comment: This is spot on. Thanks a lot Arun!